# Moving window sum on a boollean array, with steps.

Tags: python, numpy

I'm struggling with creating a moving window sum function that calculates the number of `True` values in a given numpy Boolean array `my_array`, with a window size of `n` and in jumping steps of `s`.

For example, consider array `my_array = [True, True, False, False, True, False, True]`

the sum of a moving window of size `n = 2` and with steps `s = 2` should yield `result = [2, 0, 1, 1]`, notice that the last window contains only one value.

I was trying my luck with `itertools` but to no avail.

Any help would be kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you tagged `numpy`:

```
my_array = [True, True, False, False, True, False, True]
n = 2
s = 2
result = np.convolve(my_array, np.ones(n, ), mode='valid')[::s]
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Straight forward.
Following code should do.

```
def fun(arr, n, s):
    res = []

    for i in range(0, len(arr), s):
        res.append(sum(arr[i:i+n]))

    return res

my_array = [True, True, False, False, True, False, True]
print(fun(my_array, 2, 2))
```

Comment: It works, thanks! though @dobkind solution seems more concise.