# Downsample with average method

Tags: python

I have a `2` dimensional data frame and i would like to downsample row-wise. So if i have a `100x2000` dataframe i would like it to be `100x500` for example. I have tried rolling mean but the dimensions of the output is being resampled column based and is still the original shape.
Trying to look for other ways i also found signal.resample but i believe it does not fit my scenario. If i have `[2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18]` i would like to have as an output `[4,10,16]` which means a sliding window of `3` numbers, while computing the average

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53040901/moving-window-sum-on-a-boollean-array-with-steps/53041350#53041350) example for moving average followed by resampling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `numpy.convolve`:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18])
n = 3
window = (1.0 / n) * np.ones(n,)
res = np.convolve(arr, window, mode='valid')[::n]
```

For 2 x N array:

```
from scipy import signal

arr = np.array([[2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18], [12,14,16,18,110,112,114,116,118]])
window = (1.0 / n) * np.ones((1, n))
#res = np.convolve(arr, window, mode='valid')[::n]
res = signal.convolve2d(arr, window, mode='valid')[:, ::n]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def mean_pandas(your_df, start_roling=0, mean_roling = 3):
    a = [df.iloc[:,range(i,i+mean_roling)].mean(axis=1) for i in range(start_roling,len(df),mean_roling) if i+mean_roling<=len(df)]
    b = pd.DataFrame(np.array(a).T)
    return b

mean_pandas(your_df, 0, 3)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The problem with iloc is that i dont actually compute the average what i want is [(2+4+6)/3, (8+10+12)/3, (14+16+18)/3] . Basically computing the average for every 3 numbers so my resulting data frame will be 1/3 of the original one

Comment: Try fixed answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
A = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.random.randint(10, size=(18, 18)))
pd.DataFrame({i: A[A.index[i*3: i*3 + 3]].mean(axis=1).tolist() for i in range(A.shape[1]//3)})
```

Comment: That seems to do what i want but for some reason with my own Data frame i get NaN values as a result, because i have float number i guess. Adding astype(float) didnt seem to do the trick

Comment: How could i fix the NaN issue?

Comment: This is not float issue. it will work if you put in A = A / 3